# Return HTTP Status Code 301 for all pages ending on .php

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect

How would I redirect all pages on my website that have /de/*.php or /en/*.php in the URL? I dont want to redirect domain.com/index.php though, only domain.com/de/.php or /en/*.php.

Comment: A 301 redirect, right but... Where to?

Comment: to the main domain only, so to domain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule

```
RewriteRule ^(en|de)/(.*?)\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! I added it to my .htaccess but domain.com/de/test.php still gives me a 404 instead of 301.

Comment: Did you put **RewriteEngine On** before ? Is your htaccess in root folder ? Are *mod_rewrite* enabled and htaccess allowed in your Apache config ?

Comment: I did, however the .htaccess was pretty long and at the bottom it didnt work. I moved it up right after RewriteEngine On and it works like a charm now. Thank you!